# What does next = __next__ do?

Tags: python

I saw `next = __next__` occur in multiple places in OOP code.

What is the purpose of this? It works for me without this line just as well.

```py
class Iter:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.data = value


    def __iter__(self):
        self.ix = 0
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.ix == len(self.data):
            raise StopIteration

        else:
            item = self.data[self.ix]
            self.ix += 1
            return item

    next = __next__

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = Iter([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 ])
    for i in x:
        print(i)
```

Comment: It lets it work with versions prior to [that method being renamed](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3114/), i.e. Python 2.x.

Comment: For a proper cross-compat iterator, the class should probably inherit from object too I guess.

Comment: @wim Old-style classes could implement the iterator protocol as well, though there would be other reasons to prefer making `Iter` a new-style class in Python 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's for backwards compatibility with Python 2. Per [What's new in Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#operators-and-special-methods):

> [PEP 3114](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3114): the standard `next()` method has been renamed to `__next__()`.